# Invalid class name. Class names cannot start with an underscore IOS

Tags: ios

I am getting this error when I compile successfully and the app launches, 1 time out of 3:

```
2015-03-26 12:39:32.294 Cleverly[1689:136981] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid class name. Class names cannot start with an underscore.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109943a75 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001095dcbb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001099439ad +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   Cleverly                            0x0000000104f0f50d +[PFObject(Private) _assertValidInstanceClassName:] + 128
    4   Cleverly                            0x0000000104f0974a -[PFObject(Private) initWithClassName:isPointer:] + 74
    5   Cleverly                            0x0000000104f09b82 +[PFObject(Private) objectWithClassName:isPointer:] + 151
    6   Cleverly                            0x0000000104f17163 +[PFObject objectWithoutDataWithClassName:objectId:] + 158
    7   Cleverly                            0x0000000104f0facf +[PFObject(Private) _objectFromDataFile:error:] + 571
    8   Cleverly                            0x0000000104f66b34 +[PFUser currentUser] + 581
    9   Cleverly                            0x0000000104f2e26d -[PFQuery _user] + 43
    10  Cleverly                            0x0000000104f2e83d -[PFQuery _findObjectsAsync:after:] + 104
    11  Cleverly                            0x0000000104f30860 -[PFQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:] + 288
    12  Cleverly                            0x0000000104dc873e -[ServerManager uploadOrDeleteMyUserMissingSyncFiles] + 318
    13  Cleverly                            0x0000000104dce7e6 +[ServerManager uploadOrDeleteMyUserMissingSyncFiles] + 102
    14  Cleverly                            0x0000000104d8d593 __57-[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]_block_invoke + 35
    15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000109e21186 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000109e40614 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000109e2a552 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1768
    18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000109e2bb17 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 111
    19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010a1c5637 _pthread_wqthread + 729
    20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010a1c340d start_wqthread + 13
)
```

I think it has something to do with adding ParseSDK with CocoaPods. Any ideas? Would it crash even if it was on the store?

Comment: It occurs when you make an asynchronous request and try to use data before finishing request. Also make sure you put set parse appid and key before any call to parse operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It occurs when you make an asynchronous request and try to use data before finishing request. Put for example a loader to see exactly when your async call finished loading data. Also make sure you put/ set parse appid and key **[Parse setApplicationId:clientKey:]**, **before** any call to parse operations (such as **PFUser** user). It can crash even in App Store due async not finished loading full data. I think that is the reason you get exception random.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how do I "Put for example a loader to see exactly when your async call finished loading data"?

Comment: You are right, I do call an asynchronous function before setting the key